# Performance tuning for iOS Leaves Page Flip Transition

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using the GitHub leaves library to implement a PDF Reader with page flip transition. Every thing is working perfect in iPad/iPhone simulator. But when I installed the same on device, the page flip transition on landscape mode is getting slowed. ie, When two pages are showing. Can anybody give me any suggestion to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, of course iPhone Simulator is faster, since the processor of your computer is much faster than the one in your iPhone. It highly depends on the device performance, i.e. on an iPhone 3GS it will be slower than on a 4S.

Comment: Thank you sebastian for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading your PDF images from disk as the user flips? Preloading them in the background could help speed things up.

Comment: Actually this was happening when two pages are showing at a time. So I changed to single page in landscape mode too.